# ¿Se escribe "deprisa" o "de prisa"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, expresiones, adverbios

Mis niños tienen un cuento en casa en el que está escrita la expresión *de prisa* no una, sino dos veces. Yo siempre había pensado que se escribía *deprisa*, todo junto, pero al verlo dos veces en el libro ya me hizo dudar.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta? ¿*Deprisa* o *de prisa*?

Answer (score 3):

Pues resulta que ambas formas están admitidas. Consultando el diccionario vemos:

> **[deprisa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CGIX0S0)**
>
> Tb. **de prisa**.
>
> De *de<sup>2</sup>* y *prisa*.
>
> 1. adv. Con rapidez o celeridad.

Bien, las dos formas valen, pero ¿hay alguna más correcta que la otra? El DPD nos lo resuelve:

> **[deprisa](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=deprisa)**. ‘Rápidamente, con celeridad’: *«Qué deprisa lees»* (FnGómez *Viaje* [Esp. 1985]). Aunque se recomienda su escritura en una sola palabra, también es admisible la grafía en dos palabras: *«Se puso de prisa el sombrero»* (Zaldívar *Capablanca* [C. Rica 1995]).

La RAE recomienda, por tanto, su escritura como una sola palabra: *deprisa*.

No es el único adverbio al que le sucede esto. [Un artículo de la Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/uso-y-norma-del-castellano-adverbios-y-locuciones-adverbiales-4886/) aclara que se admiten las siguientes formas:

- *[Enseguida](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FcokwxD)* y *en seguida*.
- *[Aprisa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3JeRveK)* y *a prisa*.
- *[Enfrente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FJ7TTXF)* y *en frente*.
- *[Entretanto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FoTaHzU)* y *entre tanto*.

E incluso alguna que otra no recogida por dicho artículo:

- *[Sobremanera](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y8FXNo7)* y *sobre manera*.